# Rails Migration changing column to use Postgres arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

I am trying to change a column in my database so that it can use the Postgres array data type.
Currently the table column is of type string.

I am using the following migration to convert it:

```
def change
  change_column :table, :dummy_column, :text, array: true, default: []
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "dummy_column" cannot be cast automatically to type     character varying[]
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
: ALTER TABLE "table" ALTER COLUMN "dummy_column" TYPE character varying(255) 
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: you can use change_column :table, :dummy_column, :string, array: true, default: [] instead of text it may resolve your problem

Answer (score 37, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't know how to automatically convert a column of `varchar` into an array of `varchar`. It doesn't know what you might intend, because it has no way to know what format you think the current values are in.

So you need to tell it; that's what the `USING` clause is for.

ActiveRecord doesn't seem to explicitly support the `USING` clause (not surprising, as it barely supports even the most basic database features). You can specify your own SQL text for the migration, though.

Assuming your strings are comma separated and may not themselves contain commas, for example:

```
def change
  change_column :table, :dummy_column, "varchar[] USING (string_to_array(dummy_column, ','))"
end
```

(I don't use Rails myself and haven't tested this, but it's consistent with the syntax used in examples elsewhere).

Answer (score 21):

Using Rails 4.2 on postgresql 9.4 I was looking to do this and preserve my pre-existing string data as the first element in one element arrays.

It turns out that postgresql cannot coerce a string into a text array without a USING expression to tell it how.

After much fiddling with delicate postgres syntax, I found a good middle way with active record:

```
def change
  change_column :users, :event_location, :text, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(event_location, ','))"
end
```

The only direct postgresql there is the `(string_to_array() )` function call. [Here are the docs on that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html)--note that you have to supply a delimiter.

Answer (score 5):

Using Rails 4.2 on postgresql 9.4 with a down and a up, base on lrrthomas response.
Note: your starting column should have a default of nil

```
class ChangeEmailAndNumberColumnForContact < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :contacts, :mobile_number, :text, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(mobile_number, ','))"
    change_column :contacts, :email, :text, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(email, ','))"
  end

  def down
    change_column :contacts, :mobile_number, :text, array: false, default: nil, using: "(array_to_string(mobile_number, ','))"
    change_column :contacts, :email, :text, array: false, default: nil, using: "(array_to_string(email, ','))"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def change

    change_column :table, :dummy_column, :string, array: true, default: '{}'

end
```

Notice:

it's specified as data type :string with array: true to default the column to an empty array ( [] ), you use default: '{}'

Comment: This does not work for me, I actually tried it before. I get the same error.

Comment: @ril Sorry I am not sure why you are getting same problem, but I have tried in my local system it was worked

Comment: May be the rails version - Is this supported only in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like below:

```
change_column :table, :column, :string, array: true, default: {}, using: "(string_to_array(column, ','))"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To improve readability, please [format your block code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_column :table, :dummy_column, :string, array: true
change_column_default :table, :dummy_column, []
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: I can confirm this works.