# Rails where word count in string column greater than?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to filter records by how many words exist in a certain column.

the following works, but of course returns a character count...I need a word count

```
 Flight.where("length(route) > 3")
```

Is there a rails way (or any way) to do this?

This is getting closer (its right out of the rails docs) but results in error

```
 Flight.where("array_length(route, 1) >= 3")

 ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
 ERROR:  function array_length(character varying, integer) does not exist
```

Docs also suggest using HAVING .. also not working

```
Flight.having("route.count > ?", 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split to create an array from a string with words spaced by whitespace within the string and count the total.

```
Flight.select(:route).select { |flight| flight.route.split(" ").length > 3 }
```

Comment: Data type array didnt work for me after all.  I reverted back to basic string type column.  This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

`Flight.where("array_length(route, 1) >= 3")` does work, but **the column must be set as type array.**

see this post for more [Rails Migration changing column to use Postgres arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550066/rails-migration-changing-column-to-use-postgres-arrays/22550469#22550469)

Comment: Perfect answer for newer versions of PSQL when array columns are introduced.. Instead of manipulating array in memory, let Db server handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want quite a naïve definition of "word" as "things with spaces in between", split the string and get the length of the resulting array.

In plain SQL, that'd be:

```
SELECT array_length(string_to_array(route, ' '), 1);
```

e.g.

```
SELECT array_length(string_to_array('this is - five, words', ' '), 1);
```

If you want to get fancier and ignore punctuation etc, use `regexp_split_to_array`. You can also look at using `to_tsvector` to create a stemmed and de-duplicated form if desired.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I'm using ActiveRecord.  Postgres offers an array column type that, if set up correctly, provides Flight.where("array_length(route, 1) >= 3").  I didnt know I needed the column to be of type array in order for that to work.