# Rails - force array: true to serialized field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, migration

In my Rails app's **schema.rb** I have:

```
create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "venue_id"
  t.integer  "rating",              limit: 2
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
  t.string   "treatments"
end
```

"treatment" is a serialized field:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :treatments
  ...
end
```

I need to migrate "treatments" field to:

```
t.string   "treatments", default: [], null: false, array: true
```

What would the appropriate migration look like?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `change_column` method in your migration.

```
change_column :reviews, :treatments, :string, array: true, default: [], null: false
```

Check here for more details and options: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

Comment: I will migrate the column and followup.. Am I going to lose data in that column? Would be the serialized data converted to array?

Comment: Are you using postgres? I don't believe postgres will be able to convert your string into an array of strings on it's own automatically. So if you just run this migration verbatim you will likely lose data. I haven't tested it personally though.

Comment: Based on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138239/456673) you may be able to add something like this to your `change_column` call: `using: "(string_to_array(treatments, ','))"`. But again, haven't tested it myself.