# Change column type from text to array of string (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to change column type from text to array of string, so I use this migration

```
class ChangeEmailsAndPhonesToArrayOfString < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    change_table :hotels do |t|
      t.change :emails, :string, array: true, default: []
      t.change :phones, :string, array: true, default: []
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :hotels do |t|
      t.change :emails, :text
      t.change :phones, :text
    end
  end
end
```

But I get this error when I run rails db:migrate

***PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "emails" cannot be cast automatically to type character varying[]
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING emails::character varying[]".***

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550469/4414956 ?

Comment: Thanks for the link is very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550066/rails-migration-changing-column-to-use-postgres-arrays/22550469#22550469) the following code works for me

```
def up
  change_table :hotels do |t|
    t.change :emails, :string, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(emails, ','))"
    t.change :phones, :string, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(phones, ','))"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error text specifies, you have to specify a cast to do this data type change in migration.

You can use it as below:

```
class ChangeEmailsAndPhonesToArrayOfString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :hotels do |t|
      t.change :emails, 'text ARRAY USING emails::character varying[]', default: []
      t.change :phones, 'text ARRAY USING phones::character varying[]', default: []
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :hotels do |t|
      t.change :emails, :text
      t.change :phones, :text
    end
  end
end
```

In above example, we are specifying an explicit cast to `text[]` type for given fields.

However, You might have to explicitly convert your data, if you have, in your table.